# Linq selecting items that exist in both list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 list:

```
myObject object1 = new myObject(id = 1, title = "object1"};
myObject object2 = new myObject(id = 2, title = "object2"};
myObject object3 = new myObject(id = 3, title = "object3"};

//List 1
List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>{object1, object2, object3};

//List 2
List<int> idList = new List<int>{2, 3};
```

Is there a way using Linq to pull only the objects in the first list that exist in the second list so that I am left with:

```
{object2, object3}
```

I looked at intersect but it seems that this will only work if both list are of the same type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

LINQ Solution:

```
myObjectList = myObjectList.Where(X => idList.Contains(X.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
IEnumerable<myObject> matches = myObjectList.Join(
    idList,
    o => o.Id,
    id => id,
    (o, id) => o);
```

Comment: @ Lee : There should be a variable name.  `IEnumerable<myObject>"variablename"=......`. Please edit

Answer (score 3):

The official LINQ solution as of .Net 6 is [`IntersectBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0):

```cs
var matches = myObjectList.IntersectBy(idList, o => o.Id);
```