# filter by list in an attribute that is also a list C#

Tags: c#, .net, filter

I have a class named **SchoolClass**, which has a **list of students** as attribute.
Then I have a search filter, in which I can search by a **list of students** and I have to return all the SchoolClasses where those students are part of their "list of students".

```
 public class SchoolClass
 {
    public List<string> students { get; set; }
 }

 List<string> searchedStudents = new List<string>
        { "Brian","Adrian","Matt","Chloe"};
```

So I have a list of SchoolClasses:

```
List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses = new List<SchoolClass>();
```

SchoolClass 1 ==>

```
//(it should return it because it matches Brian, one of the searchedStudents)
schoolClasses[0].students = { "Brian","Zara"};
```

SchoolClass 2 ==>

```
//(it shouldn't return it because there are no matches)
schoolClasses[1].students = { "Sophie","Zara"};
```

Comment: Have you attempted something yet? Do you want to use a for/foreach loop, or Linq, or something else? Is this data all in memory, or does it translate to an SQL query?

Comment: It is all in memory, I've tried some things but I'm not getting it. I'm using Linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq selecting items that exist in both list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913398/linq-selecting-items-that-exist-in-both-list)

Comment: thank you for sharing, but not really, because the "id" attribute in that question is not a list

Comment: what is the example input data?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: There aren't any [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is some sort of school work / project.
please make sure that you actually understand the answer and learn some sort of lesson out of it!
since this isnt a very data intense operation (with billions of entries) we can simply use go over the lists and search for the students.
if you got huge amounts of data to go through, you should consider different data structures (eg. hashtables).

```
//polulate the list with data
SchoolClass schoolClass1 = new SchoolClass();
SchoolClass schoolClass2 = new SchoolClass();
SchoolClass schoolClass3 = new SchoolClass();

schoolClass1.students = new List<string> { "Brian", "Adrian", "Matt" };
schoolClass2.students = new List<string> { "Adrian", "Matt" };
schoolClass3.students = new List<string> { "Brian", "Matt", "Chloe" };

List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses = new List<SchoolClass>();
schoolClasses.Add(schoolClass1);
schoolClasses.Add(schoolClass2);
schoolClasses.Add(schoolClass3);

//set our filter
List<string> searchedStudents = new List<string> { "Brian", "Chloe" };

//filter the data by going over the lists
List<SchoolClass> classesWithSearchedStudents = new List<SchoolClass>();
for (int classIterator = 0; classIterator < schoolClasses.Count(); classIterator++)
{
    for (int filterIterator = 0; filterIterator < searchedStudents.Count(); filterIterator++)
    {
        //comparing with our filter and add class to the results list
        if (schoolClasses[classIterator].students.Contains(searchedStudents[filterIterator]))
        {
            classesWithSearchedStudents.Add(schoolClasses[classIterator]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

printResult(classesWithSearchedStudents);
```

just for demonstration, here is a more compact version using linq

```
var searchResult = new List<SchoolClass>();
foreach (var student in searchedStudents)
{
    searchResult.AddRange(schoolClasses.Where(x => x.students.Contains(student)));
}
searchResult = searchResult.Distinct().ToList();
printResult(searchResult);
```

for printing the answer, i used this function:

```
private static void printResult(List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses)
{
    for (int classIterator = 0; classIterator < schoolClasses.Count(); classIterator++)
    {
        Console.Write("found class with students: ");
        for (int studentIterator = 0; studentIterator < schoolClasses[classIterator].students.Count; studentIterator++)
        {
            Console.Write(schoolClasses[classIterator].students[studentIterator] + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

output:

> found class with students: Brian, Adrian, Matt,
>
> found class withstudents: Brian, Matt, Chloe,

Comment: You may wish to do a Intersect or Join over Where/Contains https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153688/intersect-and-any-or-contains-and-any-which-is-more-efficient-to-find-at-least

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly:
You want to filter all schoolclasses that have "any" student from the filterlist in their student list.

If that assumption is correct than here you go.

Here's a simpeler and shorter function you can use.
It has one less for loop and cuts off whenever it finds 1 of the students.

It looks through all classes and sees if "any" of the filtered students are in there".

```cs
public IEnumerable<SchoolClass> FindMatches(List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses, List<string> namesFilter)
{
    return schoolClasses.FindAll(schoolClass => schoolClass.students.Any(student => namesFilter.Contains(student)));

}
```

Obviously you can get the single line out of the method, but I thought I post it like this so you have an idea of the inputs and what the variable names actually are.

Comment: @gunr2171. Agreed of course. I don't disagree on the downvote. Hopefully he'll takes it to heart

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check whether two lists contain any identical values is to use [`.Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) and [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) (both methods are found in the *System.Linq* namespace).

`.Intersect()` returns an `IEnumerable` of all *distinct* objects that are found in both lists.

By using `listA.Intersect(listB).Any()`, you basically get the answer to the question

> *Are there any items that exists in both `listA` and `listB`?*

In your example, the intersection of each school class's students with the searched students  would result in the following (pseudo code):

**School class 1**

> schoolClasses[0].Students **.Intersect(** searchedStudents **)**
>
> = { "Brian", "Zara" } **.Intersect(** { "Brian", "Adrian", "Matt", "Chloe" } **)**
>
> = { "Brian" }

`"Brian"` is the only student that is present in both lists.

**School class 2**

> schoolClasses[1].Students **.Intersect(** searchedStudents **)**
>
> = { "Sophie", "Zara" } **.Intersect(** { "Brian", "Adrian", "Matt", "Chloe" } **)**
>
> = { }

No student is present in both lists.

Now, let's imagine school class 3 (`schoolClasses[2]`) existed and had the following students:

```
{ "Stuart", "Chloe", "Adrian", "Maya", "Chloe" }
```

An intersection of school class 3's students and the searched students would result in:

**School class 3**

> schoolClasses[2].Students **.Intersect(** searchedStudents **)**
>
> = { "Stuart", "Chloe", "Adrian", "Maya", "Chloe" } **.Intersect(** { "Brian", "Adrian", "Matt", "Chloe" } **)**
>
> = { "Chloe", "Adrian" }

Both `"Chloe"` and `"Adrian"` are present in both lists.

Note how `"Chloe"` is present *twice* in the school class's student list, but only *once* in the result from the intersection. Seeing as your need simply is to know *whether* a student name is present in both lists, (and not *how many times* a student name is present in either list,) `.Intersect()` nonetheless suits your use case.

---

So, to the implementation.

If your `SchoolClass` class looks like this:

```csharp
public class SchoolClass
{
     public List<string> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and you define `searchedStudents` and `schoolClasses` as follows:

```csharp
List<string> searchedStudents = new() { "Brian", "Adrian", "Matt", "Chloe" };

List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses = new()
{
     new() { Students = new() { "Brian", "Zara" } },
     new() { Students = new() { "Sophie", "Zara" } },
};
```

, the intersection may be implemented as follows, using a `foreach` loop:

```csharp
var matchingSchoolClasses = new List<SchoolClass>();

foreach (var schoolClass in schoolClasses)
{
    if (schoolClass.Students.Intersect(searchedStudents).Any())
    {
        matchingSchoolClasses.Add(schoolClass);
    }
}
```

or as follows, using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0), also from the *System.Linq* namespace:

```csharp
var matchingSchoolClasses = schoolClasses
    .Where(schoolClass => schoolClass.Students.Intersect(searchedStudents).Any())
    .ToList();
```

Either implementation will result in `matchingSchoolClasses` containing *one* object. That one object is school class 1 (`schoolClasses[0]`), which contains the following students:

> { "Brian", "Zara" }

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a7ocsN).